# Crashlytics had a problem uploading the deobs file

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics

I'm found that crash reports became unreadable because of obfuscation.
From crashlytics log i'm found exception

```
    [DEBUG] (Execution worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - POST file: /home/...-875c- 
    4f7e9d519d53.zip to URL: https://cm.crashlytics.com/api/v3/platforms/android/code_mappings
    [DEBUG] (Execution worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Crashlytics using custom proxy 
    settings: :80
    [WARN] (Execution worker for ':') com.crashlytics  - Crashlytics had a problem uploading the 
    deobs file. Please check network connectivity and try again.
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be empty
    at com.crashlytics.reloc.org.apache.http.util.Args.containsNoBlanks(Args.java:84)
    at com.crashlytics.reloc.org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:80)
    at com.crashlytics.reloc.org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:99)
    at com.crashlytics.api.net.proxy.ProxySettings.getConfig(ProxySettings.java:39)
    at com.crashlytics.api.RestfulWebApi.sendFile(RestfulWebApi.java:703)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.DeobsUploader.uploadDeobsFile(DeobsUploader.java:60)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.project.DeobsUploader.uploadDeobfuscationFiles(DeobsUploader.java:37)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:629)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgsInternal(DeveloperTools.java:348)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.gradleMain(DeveloperTools.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:366)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder.this$2$callDevtoolsWrappingRuntimeExceptions(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder$_crashlyticsUploadDeobs_closure6.doCall(FabricTaskBuilder.groovy:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:104)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:326)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:427)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:647)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:620)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
```

Has anyone encountered this problem

Comment: I want to clarify the answer by @Stanislav Bondar. Just go to ~/.gradle/gradle.properties and delete the above values

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm quite sure that problem is started when i'm installed standalone canary build of Android Studio 4. Many thanks to mr. Martin Zeitler, his answer
prompted me in the right direction. The problem was in root gradle properties `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file.

It has

```
   #Fri Jan 24 13:51:37 EET 2020
   systemProp.http.proxyHost=
   systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
   systemProp.https.proxyHost=
   systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```

and removing `systemProp` variables make uploading deobfuscation works back.

Comment: also you will have to delete these lines from ~/.gradle/gradle.properties in your User directory

Comment: Thank you @Mojtaba, that was exactly the issue for me.

Comment: Must! Remove/Comment above mentioned lines from "gradle.properties" in your system user directory (Root), not from project's "gradle.properties" as i was looking in wrong directory and file.

Comment: @Muhammadwaris The problem was in root gradle properties .gradle/gradle.properties file. Is there any word about project's gradle ?

Comment: @StanislavBondar you mentioned very precisely about the Root gradle file but my Bad I was looking in the wrong directory. That's. why added the comment so no one make the same silly mistake like i did. Sorry if I sounded wrong !
Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

It reads: `Crashlytics using custom proxy settings: :80`. While `https://` always is port `:443`.

That proxy does not like SSL or the other way around, since it's meant to be end-to-end encryption.

`Host name may not be empty` likely comes from `systemProp.https.proxyHost`.

Comment: Thank you for response. Migration to Firebase was made before this and there is no proxy settings in local network or android studio settings.