# New build type fails with error: CrashlyticsOrgIdException: Could not fetch Crashlytics Org Id

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have a project that has been using Crashytics for a while.  Today, I added a new build type by copying/pasting one of the existing blocks under buildTypes{...} and renaming it.

The build type includes a different application id suffix, so I logged into the Firebase console, registered a new app using the new application id suffix, and downloaded the generated google-services.json file and placed it in a src folder with the same name as the build type.

Attempts to build the new variant fail with the message:

> Execution failed for task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileR1Qa'.
>
> java.io.IOException: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.exception.CrashlyticsOrgIdException: Could not fetch Crashlytics Org Id

The other variants build without issue.  I have tried gradle sync, cleaning and rebuilding, as well as invalidating cache and restarting Android Studio.  But the error persists.

I've searched for Crashlytics Org Id, but can find no mention of it in the documentation, or the wider internet, save a couple other SO posts that do not shed much light.

What is Crashlytics Org Id, and from where is it retrieved?

UPDATE: It seems that Google is trying to be a little too automagical here.
After adding the google-services.json file to your project, literally need to open up the Crashlytics section of your Firebase console, left-click the next steps (including the step that just opens the documentation) until it says "build and run your app" and do that with the console open.  I'm in that habit of right-clicking links and opening them in other tabs/windows and apparently this does not trigger a necessary script on that page.

Comment: if you have changed the google services json file from another firebase account account then make sure to setup firebase crashlytics in firebase console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this error when `Crashlytics` was not completely configured in `Firebase Console` Make sure that you have added your new build type as separate app in console and then go to `Crashlytics` section select new app and complete all three steps there.

After this build again, build should succeed.

Comment: I did use the Firebase Console to add an app and gave it the package name of my new build type.  I downloaded the google-services.json file for that app and put it in my project.

Comment: @duggulous Also make sure that now you go to crashlytics section select your app and then complete onboarding for that particular app  there. You will see 3 steps that you need to complete for the sake of it.

Comment: This is the best answer. I have two flavors in my project and one of them was not correctly set in the Crashlytics dashboard, after finishing initialization there all projects starts to build successfully.

Answer (score 3):

in my case, I changed the

build.gradle(project)

> classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta02'

to :

> classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'

And then rebuild.
The problem solved.

Comment: This worked for me, after trying many things. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try to check again your plugin in gradle, I think you forgot to add some plugins

Comment: I don't think it's a missing plugin issue, because other build types in the same file build correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added your app in the firebase project settings with the correct package name and that you have downloaded the `google-services.json` file and put it into the app.

1. Open Firebase Console
2. Select your project
3. In the left menu next to `Project Overview` you can navigate to the `Project settings`.
4. Use the `Add app` button or check the existing package name for the app.
5. Download `google-services.json` and put into your project.

Comment: I did add the app to my firebase project.  I've double-checked that the package name is correct, and that it shows up in the google-services.json file.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

just remove

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.0.0-beta02'
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

build and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there was a problem with the Gradle proxy settings for me (which happened when I installed the Android Studio 4).
Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59948613/6140436